# POST service with Rest API callout method for HTTPS

Tags: rest-api, post

I have a requirement for POST service.
I am using the Rest API callout approach.
The end point is in http.
The client is asking for using https end point.

My question is what is the procedure for using the Rest Api Callout  with https. Is it similar to that of the http approach? How will I   tackle the issue of uploading the necessary certificates for end    point with https ?

Comment: It's similar though but sometimes the authentication process can be changed as per the implementation. Did you try by just changing the endpoint url in the code?

Comment: You cannot have any https certificate, the SSL certificate should be CA certified and from the below list.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000007225&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=1